# How do I test a c# data type with a string array in it for values?

Tags: c#

I have a c# object's property

> response.errors

returning a value that looks like this when I hover over it.

> {string[0]}

Is this a Json object with strings in it?

I'm looking for a way to test if it has an empty value

> {string[0]}

or has values

> {string[2]}

Comment: `response.errors.Count()`?  `response.errors.Any()`?  If `errors` is an array then what's stopping you from checking how many elements the array has?  What does JSON have to do with this?  It's not really clear what the problem is.  Perhaps you can provide a code sample to demonstrate?

Comment: 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Any', 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Count'

Comment: It's pretty unusual to not be using LINQ these days, but I guess: `response.errors.Length`?  In your IDE, when you type the period after `response.errors`, it should tell you what's available.  If it doesn't, you need to use a better IDE.  (Visual Studio seems like the obvious choice here.)  Failing that, you can also always look up the built-in types you're using on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array

Answer (score 1):

Its not a JSON object

`{string[0]}` means that its an object with an empty array of strings in it

If you want to verify if the array is empty, use `response.errors.Any()` from `System.Linq`

If you want to verify if the strings are empty, use `foreach(var error in response.errors) { return error.Length }`